# Can video game fonts (or other least protectable content) be recreated without breaching a contract?

Tags: breach-of-contract, video-games

For instance Valve has a policy that recreating fonts/typefaces from their games (that are not protected by copyright) is a breach of the Steam Subscriber Agreement (SSA). But as far as I know the SSA does not apply when the user has never used Steam, and these font(s) can be obtained from the websites of the respective game(s) for recreation (they do *not* have hotlinking/download protection), so why this policy exists?

Comment: I searched the document for the words "font" and "typeface" and found nothing. Can you point out the section of the agreement you are talking about? Perhaps quote it verbatim?

Comment: Well, what some customer service representative claimed in some email is probably not very relevant. They are probably instructed by the legal department to say "no" to everything in order to not accidentally grant anyone any rights they aren't supposed to have.

Comment: Do you have a source on the typefaces not being protected by copyright?

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim US copyright office themselves says that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be in breach of a contract, one must be in [privity of contract](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privity_of_contract) with the other party.

I, for example, am not in privity of contract with Valve. If I were to reproduce their fonts or typefaces, or even if I were to infringe Valve's copyright, I would still not be party to any contract that I could be in breach of.